# Using pywhatkit to automate whatsapp | python 3

Tags: python, automation, extension-methods

WhatsApp automation by using `pywhatkit` in python3 does not work well. The message is not sent automatically.

I tried to automate WhatsApp in python3 by using `pywhatkit`.

For this I wrote the following code:

```
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+4xxxxxxxxxx6", "Hi", 15, 32)
```

So now the code makes opening WhatsApp and the chat. There is also the message but the message is not sent automatically. I have to do this manually.

I can't figure out why.

Do you have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.